# Webfonts not matching between OS X and Windows

Tags: css, windows, macos, web, fonts

My personal website uses Helvetica, which is defined as the font family in my CSS. The site looks fine on OS X and iOS on all browsers, but when I view it on my Windows 7 machine it doesn't seem to render the text the same and basically looks...bad.

As I have very little knowledge about web fonts I was hoping someone could explain why different operating systems render fonts differently on the web, and is there any code tricks to present a unified style on all platforms.

Thanks for any help.

Here's the site by the way: [colm.io](http://www.colm.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the operating system has Helvetica, the browser can be able to display that, otherwise, the browser will choose other backup fonts according to your font-family attribute. Or you may look at https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started, that's for the browser automatically download the font from google and use it just for displaying, and it does not install fonts on the users' OS.

css fontface: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

css font-family:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp

compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface

I personally use Roboto family for webfonts, that is a brand new font designed by google and it can be used in android, ios, web and OS.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, it seems that each browser supports different fonts and has different ways of displaying them. By adding a few more fonts to my font-family attribute in the CSS, I can "fall back" on another font if the browser doesn't support my first preference.